# How to do a multiple choice crosstable in R

Tags: r, expss

My code...

```
library(expss)
library(haven)
X4707 <- read_sav("/home/cfmc/4707/data/4707.sav")
X4707 %>% 
    tab_cells("By phone"=qpd4_1==1,"By email"=qpd4_2==1,"Utility website"=qpd4_3==1,"Roseville Electric notification"=qpd4_4==1,"Social media"=qpd4_5==1,"Text"=qpd4_6==1,"Not sure"=qpd4_8==1) %>% 
    tab_cols(total(), qf5) %>% 
    tab_stat_cpct() %>% 
    tab_last_sig_cpct() %>% 
    tab_pivot()
```

My output looks like this...
[image]

I would like for the output to simply contain the text of the code going down the stub (By phone, By email, etc.) without the TRUE, FALSE, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to designate that you want multiple response. You have multiple choice with positional coding so you need `mdset` (m(ultiple) d(ichotomy) set) function:

```
library(expss)
library(haven)
X4707 <- read_sav("/home/cfmc/4707/data/4707.sav")
X4707 %>% 
    tab_cells(mdset("By phone"=qpd4_1==1,"By email"=qpd4_2==1,"Utility website"=qpd4_3==1,"Roseville Electric notification"=qpd4_4==1,"Social media"=qpd4_5==1,"Text"=qpd4_6==1,"Not sure"=qpd4_8==1)) %>% 
    tab_cols(total(), qf5) %>% 
    tab_stat_cpct() %>% 
    tab_last_sig_cpct() %>% 
    tab_pivot()
```